# Google Music streaming music slowly on chromium

Tags: 14.04, chromium, music

I use Chromium 45.0.2454.101 on Ubuntu 14.04 which is updated daily.
When using Google streaming music my computer gets really slow.
I checked with htop and it uses a lot of CPU power of all cores of my AMD A4.
I/O seems ok, it uses just a small portion of RAM.

Why is this service so CPU consuming when playing music because it does not happen on firefox. Is there a way to enable better performance? I would like to stick with chrome.

Answer (score 1):

For what i have search you can put the tab in the background and let it keep playing, and it will change the CPU numbers.

Another info using chromium will use more FPS to do play, because it's using html5, against flash things are really different.

```
html5 is 60 fps, flash is 30fps.
```

Try as well clean up the cache sometimes.